# Drop down menu with iframe dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue placing this z-index on top of another div. How can i make it so when it slides down it slides down over that div. If you wish to see an example i can show you over chat. Basically the dropdown box is going under another div that is below it, but i want it to hover over it.

```
<style type='text/css'>
#content {
    margin: auto 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 240px;
    border-left: 10px solid #6280c1;
    border-right: 10px solid #6280c1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 0px 100px 0px;
    display: none;
}
#bottom {
    width: 280px;
    height: 81px;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('#bottom').toggle(

function() {
    $('#content').slideDown();
}, function() {
    $('#content').slideUp();
});
});//]]>  

</script>

<div id="content">CONTENT</div>
<div id="bottom"><img src="../images/drop_fb.png" width="280" height="81"></div>
```

Comment: pls put it in jsfiddle for clearer demonstration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `position:absolute;` to the #bottom div makes it stay on top of the #content div.

```
#bottom {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `position:absolute` to every div you want to positionate by z-index, otherwise this will not work.